# Chat application on Laravel 9.x

Tags: javascript, laravel, chat

I want to make a chat application (something like on how is on Whatsapp Web). I want my application to be on laravel.

I just finished the design and the login system.

My question is about functionality.

Is it enough Laravel and Javascript or do I need something else additional?
I don't need to make a large project, its just for me to start learning the basics things and how they work.

Comment: Laravel provides full backend functionality and also frontend, so technically you don't need another language other than javascript for responsiveness.. And since it's a chatting app, you may as well use laravel websockets and set up a websocket server with laravel and make the client with Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel for backend, JS for frontend

You also need Pusher (if not big project) for (easy) real-time application and pusher-js for subscribe websocket

Comment: Thank you! I will try using pusher js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a websocket part , in order to make the app real Time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).